# Regular Expression to get rid of query string on URL rewriting dup folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm redirecting an entire folder into the duplicate folder above it. I have mod_rewrite enabled, what type of regular expression could I put in .htaccess to get rid of the: `?q=dup_folder/inspection11.htm` from the URL below? There are multiple files in the folder with various names.

Redirect Code in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /dup_folder/ http://www.example.biz/
```

It redirects to:

```
http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm?q=dup_folder/inspection11.htm
```

But I want it to redirect to:

```
http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/dup_folder/$ http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm [r=301,l]
```

Comment: That code just send the user to the file in /dup_folder/ on my server. Is there something else that should go around that code?

Comment: @JMC, my bad. Forgot RewriteEngine.

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^dup_folder/?$ http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm? [R=301,L,NC]
```

It is important to end redirected URL with `?` to get rid of any query string you may have in original URI like `dup_folder/?foo=bar` will be redirected to `http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm` discarding the original query string `foo=bar`.

`NC` is used for ignore case comparison here